# Application not loading with new GWT Maven Plugin

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I have been migrating legacy gwt-maven-plugin 2.10.0 with tbroyer gwt-maven-plugin 1.1.0, intially i did faced some compilation issue and fixed them all. After the compiliation issues are fixed the build is sucessfull but the .cache.js files being generated are much smaller is size than that was generated using the legacy plugin and the build completes much faster. Not sure if the compilation is generating all the required java script (the logs suggest that its is loading all the .gwt.xml files including the inherited modules). And now when i try to load the application on browser i could see a blank page and no java script erros in the developer tools console tab and all the resources are loading with 200 OK. Below is the maven plugin configuration.

Also the  is set to war (not set to gwt-app or gwt-lib) since the module also contains some Servlets which is included in the war.

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceLevel>11</sourceLevel>
                <skipModule>true</skipModule>
                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                <moduleName><<module name with Package>></moduleName>
                <localWorkers>2C</localWorkers>
                <logLevel>ALL</logLevel> 
                <argLine>-Xmx2048M -Xms1024m</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                 </execution>                
            </executions>
                            
        </plugin>
```

Environment using : Zulu open JDK 17.0.10 (but source level set to 11). Please help me in understanding what is going wrong. Let me know if you need more information.